# How would you say "pet" (animal kept for companion, such as a cat, a dog, or a rabbit) in Latin?

Tags: word-request

Ancient Romans kept dogs and cats as pets, right? Was there a word used to refer to animals which are kept in such a way? If so, which one?

Comment: A quick search found this in Smith and Hall, but it seems more specific than just "pet": 
_cătŭlus, f. cătŭla (strictly, a young d., a whelp, q. v.): trusty d.s, c. fideles, Hor. Dimin. cătellus, f. cătella, esp. a pet dog, Pl.: Hor._

Comment: Delicia? It's used in a few places (e.g. Catullus, Martial) in reference specifically to animals. In fact, OLD gives 'pet animal' as definition 3b.

Comment: @cnread That sounds like a good answer!

Comment: @cnread That's spot on. Seneca has *subalbam canem in deliciis habere adsueuerat*. Go ahead and answer.